# Is it OK to use "mContext" (initialized at onCreate)?

Tags: android, android-context

Is this a bad habit, and why if it is? So in every **activity** adding this right after **onCreate**...

```
mContext = this;
```

and then use it in all other cases where **context** is **required**? For example

```
Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.someString), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

**EDIT:** What if I have something like this...how the context should be passed? Because ***this*** cannot be applied (because of the **View.OnClickListener()**).

```
someButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.someButton);
someButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.warning), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is this a bad habit, and why if it is?

Yes, it is a bad habit. It is a waste of code. `this` is shorter than `mContext`, and you have an extra line of code for setting the data member.

I disagree with Mr. Damiean's suggestion of always using `getApplication()`. Use `getApplication()` when you specifically need the `Application` object. You neither need nor want the `Application` object for creating a `Toast` -- your `Activity` is a perfectly suitable `Context` to use there. The `Application` object fails to work in many places, particularly when dealing with things involving the UI.

Comment: I edited my question with another example. Tnx. for your help.

Comment: @svebee: `this` can most certainly be applied. You have to scope it with the outer class name (e.g., `MyActivityClass.this`).

Comment: I cannot emphasize enough that you should NOT use the application context for UI. This will often behave in unexpected ways, especially in Honeycomb.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` instead. Even in an OnClickListener or other subclasses you use `ActivityName.this` like this:

```
someButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.someButton);
someButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, ActivityName.this.getString(R.string.warning), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```